# Passing parameters into the Backbone events object of a backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following events for a Backbone View. Its a product view - with three tabs ("All", "Top 3", "Top 5")

Can I somehow pass a parameter into the method declaration so that it is equivalent to the following (this doesn't work)?

```
events : {
    "click #top-all":          "topProducts(1)"
    "click #top-three":      "topProducts(2)"
    "click #top-ten":         "topProducts(3)"
},
topProducts(obj){
    // Do stuff based on obj value
}
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You could put the extra argument in a data attribute on the clickable item instead; something like this:

```
<a id="top-all" data-pancakes="1">
```

And then `topProducts` can figure it out itself:

```
topProducts: function(ev) {
    var pancakes = $(ev.currentTarget).data('pancakes');
    // And continue on as though we were called as topProducts(pancakes)
    // ...
}
```

Comment: "this" points to the Backbone View here so doing a direct $(this) will not give the DOM element corresponding to the element clicked.

Comment: @papdel: Right, sorry about that. But you can use `ev.target` (where `ev` is the event) instead. Have a look at my fixed version please.

Comment: Thanks, in general $(ev.target) gets you the dom element which triggered the event so this is immensely helpful.

Comment: @papdel: Yeah, `ev.target` (when you can't rely on `this`) combined with data attributes is a great way to keep track of things.

Comment: @whistler: `{ 'click #top-all': 'topProducts', 'click #top-three': 'topProducts', ... }`.

Comment: Isn't there exist a way which is found in jquery to handle events ?
`.eventName( [eventData ], handler(eventObject) )`

Comment: @Shubhmay: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean `x.click(...)` and such? You usually let Backbone handle events through delegation.

Comment: Is there any better solution out there to this? It seems crazy to me that you can't easily pass parameters to these events functions. Is there some good reason I'm not seeing?

Comment: @streetlight: You could put functions (rather than names) in `events` but that's just shuffling things around.

Comment: @streetlight, try the below answer: arguments[0].currentTarget.id and you do not need to manipulate the DOM with an unnecessary data attribute.

Comment: Can I just say, this is stupidly complex for something that should be extremely simple. Minus 5 points from the makers of backbone.js.

Answer (score 40):

I generally prefer to do something like this:

```
events : {
   "click #top-all":    function(){this.topProducts(1);}
   "click #top-three":  function(){this.topProducts(2);}
   "click #top-ten":    function(){this.topProducts(3);}
},
topProducts(obj){
   // Do stuff based on obj value
}
```

Comment: Awesome stuff !!

Comment: Simplest is often best.  I like it!

Answer (score 9):

What you can do, is just check the id of the element which is received as currentTarget in arguments.

```
topProduct: function (e) {
    var id = e.currentTarget.id;
    if (id == "top-all") // Do something
    else if (id == "top-5") // Do something
    else if (id == "top-3") // Do something
}
```

Comment: This is actually better than the selected answer as it doesn't require any modification to the DOM.

Comment: This answer is by far better than adding an unnecessary data attribute.

Comment: If you want to get the class use `e.currentTarget.className` instead of `e.currentTarget.id`. Also, there are a lot interesting properties inside `e` object!

Comment: @DavidCorral If you look at the sample given by OP, there is an Id mentioned on all the elements on which click handlers are attached. I agree with you on interesting properties on event object.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so using closures:

```
EventObject.on(event, (function(){
    var arg = data; // Closure preserves this data
    return function(){
        doThis(arg);
    }   
})());
```